# I need help starting one method right after another method finishes, not during it

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, game-engine

I am making a game and after someone clicks, a ball moves across the screen which takes some time. I am trying to do a method after the ball stops moving.  I tried sleep and it didnt work. I also looked at asynctask and don't fully understand it.  Can someone point me in the right direction or tell me how to use asynctask with my code, thanks. I am really new to this so anything will be helpful.

This first part is the Main class which has the code for the actions in the game. The afterKick() method is the action I want to happen after the kick() method finishes.

```
    final FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    main.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.field));
    newBall = new Ball(this);
    main.addView(newBall);
        main.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                System.out.println("x:" + x + " y" + y);

                if(kick == false && attempt<10)
                {
                    setHeight(y, newBall);
                    kick(x,y,newBall,main);
                }
                afterKick();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Once the kick() method is called it goes to the class which creates the ball. The onDraw method keeps repeating until the ball no longer gets redrawn because of the invalidate.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, left, top, null);
    if(topMax>=top)
    {
        setDone(true);
    }
    else if(straight == true && top> topMax)
    {
        kickStraight();
    }
    else if(righty == true && top>topMax)
    {
        kickRight();
    }
    else if(midRight == true && top>topMax)
    {
        kickMidRight();
    }
    else if(midLeft == true && top>topMax)
    {
        kickMidLeft();
    }
    else if(lefty == true && top>topMax)
    {
        kickLeft();
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

I cant figure out how to do something after invalidate no longer restarts the onDraw method. Any help would be useful, thanks!

Comment: Can you detect when the ball is stops?

Comment: I have a max height set up depending on where you click on the ball, then the onDraw method goes through and moves up a set number each time through until it reaches the max height. In short, yes.

Answer (score 4):

AsyncTasks have a [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method which will force the program to wait for an output from the AsyncTask before continuing on. What you could do is have your AsyncTask return a value when it is completed and in your calling thread you could assign this value to a variable.

```
 AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask().execute(params);
 Object output = task.get();
```

However, using the get method will block the UI thread. A safer (and better) alternative is to make use of the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method. This will be called after the doInBackground method is complete and will run on the main UI thread.

Comment: Two quick questions, they may be a little newbish: Do I need to make a new class for the asyncTask or can I include it in the main class or the ball class that I have? and also how do I put methods into the asyncTask that each have multiple parameters in them? I am trying to understand as best as possible. If you can help me more thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes you would need to create a new class that extends AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>. The doInBackground method of an AsyncTask utilizes Varargs, so you can pass as many arguments to the method as you want. Here is a great AsyncTask tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask.

Comment: I finally was able to understand asyncTask enough to get it working. But the same problem was happening in this though because I don't think the onDraw method is being looked at as part of the method in the doInBackGround. But I was able to use sleep in async without onDraw method stopping completely, like it did when I tried sleep in my main class. Thanks for all the tips!